# Nodejs cluster use only 1 worker

Tags: node.js, node-modules, node-cluster

Why cluster module use only 1-2 workers and doesn't balance the load through all 12 workers? Site stats: 10000 daily users, 100-200 online users constantly. I am using nginx and pm2 to start the server.

Screenshot: [Ubuntu 14.04 top command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73yak.png)

My code:

```
let net = require('net'),
config = require('config'),
cluster = require('cluster'),
logger = require('packages/logger'),
os = require('os');

if(cluster.isMaster) {
let workers = [], workersCount = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? os.cpus().length : 4;
let spawn = function(i) {
    workers[i] = cluster.fork();
    workers[i].on('exit', () => {
        logger.error(`Worker ${i} is down`);
        spawn(i);
    });
};
for (let i = 0; i < workersCount; i++) {
    logger.debug(`Spawn worker №${++workers.length}`);
    spawn(i);
}
let worker_index = function(ip, len) {
    let s = '';
    for (let i = 0, _len = ip.length; i < _len; i++) {
        if (!isNaN(ip[i])) {
            s += ip[i];
        }
    }
    return Number(s) % len;
};
net.createServer({pauseOnConnect: true}, (connection) => {
    let worker = workers[worker_index(connection.remoteAddress, workersCount)];
    worker.send('sticky-session:connection', connection);
}).listen(config.default.http.port);

}else {
let server = require('config/server');
server = server.server;//just an express http server

process.on('message', (message, connection) => {
    if (message !== 'sticky-session:connection') {
        return;
    }
    server.emit('connection', connection);
    connection.resume();
});
}
```

Comment: Do you have any evidence that you ever had more work to do at any given moment than 2 workers could handle without any waiting?

Comment: No I haven't. Does cluster module use workers only if it need?And it does not balance the load across all workers?

Comment: There's certainly no requirement that it rotate fairly among all the workers when the workload is light since that would make no difference to the performance.  So, it would depend upon the internal implementation and whether it purposely rotates among them or not.  Certainly, all should come into play when the workload is heavy.  You'd probably have to look into the clustering code if you really wanted to know how it works in that regard, though I think from your observations, we know the answer.

Comment: Can I change cluster's balance strategy like in nginx upstream strategies (least_conn)?

Comment: Read here: https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_how_it_works

Comment: And, here: https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster_schedulingpolicy

Comment: Can you give me some recommendations what I should do?

Comment: Do you have an actual problem that needs solving?  If so, please describe what problem you observe.